# Nested Avro record deserialization with array type of records

Tags: java, apache-kafka, deserialization, avro

I am writing code to deserialize avro nested records with array type of records in it by using POJO's for array type record and calling as list in main POJO class for deserialization. However I am not understanding how I can use multiple schema for deserialization of the record.

Schema structure:

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "MainSchemaName",
"version": "2",
"namespace": "com.cmain",
"doc": "AExample",
"fields": [
 {
  "name": "MainABC",
  "type": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "name": "ABCarr",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "prod1",
          "type": "double"
        },
        {
          "name": "prod2",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
 },
 {
  "name": "comnsu1",
  "type": "int"
 }
 ]
}
```

Comment: The schema structure on the question is not valid

Comment: updated the schema I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a single file for each record as follow:

**ABCarr.avsc**:

```
{
      "name": "ABCarr",
      "namespace": "com.cmain",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "prod1",
          "type": "double"
        },
        {
          "name": "prod2",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
}
```

**MainSchemaName.avsc**:

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "MainSchemaName",
"version": "2",
"namespace": "com.cmain",
"doc": "AExample",
"fields": [
 {
  "name": "MainABC",
  "type": {
       "type": "array",
       "items": "com.cmain.ABCarr",
       "java-class": "java.util.List"
     }
 },
 {
  "name": "comnsu1",
  "type": "int"
 }
 ]
}
```

Then you should configure the **avro-maven-plugin** to build schemas that are required by others ( ABCarr in your case ) prior. Supposing your avro schema files are located on `src/main/resources/schema/avro` path you should specify the following to build ABCarr and then use it on MainSchemaName as type:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>schema</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/avro</sourceDirectory>
                <stringType>String</stringType>
                <createSetters>true</createSetters>
                <fieldVisibility>private</fieldVisibility>
                <imports>
                    <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/avro/ABCarr.avsc</import>
                </imports>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

So just import all **common schemas** on imports option.

Comment: I have done the same way and uses the generated java classes for the deserialization.  it is throwing null pointer exception

Comment: Can you share more details and the stacktrace?

Comment: As mentioned above I have first build the schema ABCarr.avsc
Actual Result observed: Java pojo class not created for schema ABCarr

Later I build the schema ABCarr.avsc with output directory mentioned in pom.xml and then build the MainSchemaName.avsc with type com.cmain.ABCarr.
Build failed with the error:  schema failed: Type com.cmain.ABCarr not supported.   

My second question is how I can use this multiple schema in datumReader to deserialize byterarray records?

Comment: I've updated array definition on MainSchemaName. Try with this code.
About deserialization you should use the main class that include others as reference that is **MainSchemaName** in your case

Comment: Is there any way if we can use single avro schema with nested records for deserialization??